# How to show and hide loader on Network layer in swiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have a Global Singleton network class which handles the response of the API. I want to handle the loader from this class I don't want to manage from each ViewModel individually. I just want to toggle variabe "isLoading" in the ContentView from my global Network class "APIService" But no idea how would I do that?

```
class APIService {
    static let shared = APIService()
    private let timeInterval = 60
    func makeApiTypeRequest<T: Codable>(
        url: String,
        param: [String: Any]? = nil,
        methodType: HttpMethodType,
        expecting: T.Type,
        passToken: Bool = true,
        completion: @escaping (Result<T, Error>)->Void) {
            
            guard let url = URL(string: url) else {
                return
            }
            
            var request = URLRequest(url: url, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringCacheData, timeoutInterval: TimeInterval(timeInterval))
            if let param = param {
                let finalData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: param)
                request.httpBody = finalData
            }
            
            request.httpMethod = methodType.rawValue //"post"
            request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "content-type")
        
            
            if passToken {
                let data = KeychainHelper.standard.read(service: Constant.tokenKey)
                if let data = data {
                    let accessToken = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
                    if let accessToken, accessToken != "" {
                        let headers = ["Content-Type": "application/json", "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken]
                        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
                    }
                }
            }
        
            
            
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data,response,error) in
            do {
                
                if let error = error {
                    completion(.failure(error))
                    return
                }
                
                if let data = data {
                    if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                        switch httpStatus.statusCode {
                        case 400:
                            completion(.failure(CustomError.forbidden))
                        case 200:
                            let respObj = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
                            completion(.success(respObj))
                        case 500:
                            // token expired
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("test.token.expired"), object: nil)
                            }
                            completion(.failure(CustomError.tokenExpired))
                        default:
                            completion(.failure(CustomError.unknown))
                        }
                    }
                    
                } else {
                    completion(.failure(CustomError.unknown))
                    print("no data found")
                }
            } catch(let error) {
                completion(.failure(CustomError.unknown))
                print("Error A123 \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }.resume()
        
    }
    
}
```

ContenView

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var session: SessionManager
    @State var showMenu: Bool = false
    @State var isLoading: Bool = false
    @State var isAppInstalled: Bool = false
    
    let pub = NotificationCenter.default
                .publisher(for: NSNotification.Name("test.token.expired"))
    
    var body: some View {
        return NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                if isAppInstalled {
                    if session.currentUserState == .loggedIn {
                        GeometryReader { geometry in
                            TabContainer(showMenu: $showMenu)
                                .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
                            if self.showMenu {
                                MenuView()
                                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width/2)
                            }
                        }
                        
                    } else {
                        LoginView(showMenu: $showMenu)
                    }
                    
                    if isLoading {
                        Loading()
                            .ignoresSafeArea()
                    }
                } else {
                    GettingStartedView(isInstalled: $isAppInstalled)
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                if GettingStartedPersistance.shared.isAppAlreadyInstalled() {
                    isAppInstalled = true
                }
                
            }
            .onReceive(pub) { (output) in
                self.session.signout()
            }
            
        }//.allowsHitTesting(!self.isLoading)
        
        
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Sample ViewModel

```
class LoginViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var loginResponse:LoginResponseModel?
    @Published var isNavigatedToDashBaord = false
    @Published var errorMessage = ""
    @Published var isErrorPresented = false
    
    
    private func validateInputFields(email: String, password: String)->Bool {
        if email.isEmpty {
            errorOccured(err: "Please enter email")
            return false
        }
        
        if password.isEmpty {
            errorOccured(err: "Please enter password")
            return false
        }
        
        if !Utils.shared.isValidEmail(strToValidate: email) {
            errorOccured(err: "Please enter a valid email")
            return false
        }
        
        if password.count < 5 {
            errorOccured(err: "Password must be atleast 5 characters long")
            return false
        }
        
        return true
    }
    
    func login(email: String, password: String, completion: @escaping (()->())) {
        if !validateInputFields(email: email, password: password) {
            completion()
            return
        }
        var param = [String: Any]()
        param["username"] = email
        param["password"] = password
        APIService.shared.makeApiTypeRequest(url: APIURLConstant.loginUrl, param: param, methodType: .post, expecting: LoginResponseModel.self, passToken: false) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let loginData):
                if loginData.authToken != "" && loginData.authToken != nil {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.saveUserToken(token: loginData.authToken ?? "")
                        self.loginResponse = loginData
                        self.successlogIn()
                        completion()
                    }
                } else {
                    self.errorOccured(err: "Login failled")
                    completion()
                }
            case .failure( _):
                self.errorOccured(err: "Login failled")
                completion()
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func errorOccured(err: String) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.errorMessage = err
            self.isErrorPresented = true
        }
        
    }
    
    private func successlogIn() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.errorMessage = ""
            self.isErrorPresented = false
            self.isNavigatedToDashBaord = true
        }
        
    }
    
    private func saveUserToken(token: String) {
        let accessToken =  Data(token.utf8)
        KeychainHelper.standard.save(accessToken, service: Constant.tokenKey)
    }
}
```

Comment: In a SwiftUI context make `APIService` conform to `ObservableObject` and add a property `@Published var isLoading = false`. Set the property according to the state  inside  `makeApiTypeRequest`. In the view delete `isLoading` and use the property in the class.

Comment: can you plz explain with code

Comment: The code is in my comment. That's all you need. I see you've edited your question. Add the `@Published var isLoading = false` in the view model and set it before the API call and inside the completion handler.

Comment: couldn't get can you plz explain with an example because I don't have access to the contentView in Network class

Comment: It's the other way round: You need access to `LoginViewModel` in `ContentView`

Comment: but I am going to do so then I'll have to manage for each ViewModel and I don't want to manage the loader code for each ViewModel separately

Comment: I is there any gloabal View to which I could make like loader and Can call from anywhere like ProgressHUD in swift